# Javascript Objects doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, debugging, object

the chrome debugger shows my result. It calls it "Object". But when I try to open it as an object it is just undefined.

[image]

Can somebody explain me the difference here?

Comment: Can you post the code that is generating this output?

Comment: JavaScript Objects work fine, you are not doing it right :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `firstResponse[0]` is itself an array. try `firstResponse[0][0].com`

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the scope you are in... your script runs and your object ist scoped in some function... when the function is done you return to your window scope. while you are in your function scope your object can be accessed an written to the log... this object is unknown in other scopes and therefore undefined

```
var function1 = function(){
  var object1 = {};
  console.log(object1); //returns {}
}

var function2 = function(){
  var object2 = {};
  console.log(object2); //returns {}
  console.log(object1); //returns undefined
}

  console.log(object2); //returns undefined
  console.log(object1); //returns undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

`firstResponse[0]` refers to an array (we can tell from the opening `[` before the word "Object"); that array has an entry which is an object. So we have to index into the array to see the properties on that object:

```
firstResponse[0][0].com
// Change is ---^^^
```